# Ezekiel 28:13-14 Was Eden on a mountain?

Tags: history, eden

**Relevant Scripture**

> **Ezekiel 28:13-14**
> 3 **You were in Eden, the garden of God;**
> every precious stone was your covering,
> sardius, topaz, and diamond,
> beryl, onyx, and jasper,
> sapphire, emerald, and carbuncle;
> and crafted in gold were your settings
> and your engravings.
> On the day that you were created
> they were prepared.
> 14 You were an anointed guardian cherub.
> **I placed you; you were on the holy mountain of God;**
> in the midst of the stones of fire you walked.

So, this is a passage where a lament is made of the king of Tyre by comparing him to a guardian cherub in the Garden of Eden who had fallen.

**Question:** Are we to understand that God is accurately describing the historical geography of the Garden of Eden on a mountain in this vivid imagery designed to describe the downfall of the King of Tyre or is He actually blending multiple but originally separate geographic images to describe the ruler's downfall?

Comment: They are two separate places - Eden is one place and the mountain of God is another place.

Comment: Throughout the Bible, "mountain" is  used as a symbol of nations, kingdoms, or governments. It isn't necessarily a literal mountain in this scripture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**10 And a river went out of Eden to water the garden; and from thence it was parted, and became into four heads.** (Genesis 2)

Since water can only flow downhill, the garden of Eden had to be on a mountain. Theologically, that higher ground was the place where heaven and earth met. After the fall of man, God abandoned the earth where satan now rules, and He sits up in the heavens. All through the Old Testament, people were anticipating the reconnection of heaven and earth on a mountain and the return of the garden of Eden. Noah on top of the mount Ararat, Abraham with Isaac in Moriah, Moses and Sinai...
It was all fulfilled in Jesus being crucified on Golgotha.

**10 That in the dispensation of the fulness of times he might gather together in one all things in Christ, both which are in heaven, and which are on earth; even in him:** (Ephesians 1)

It is already but not yet, so we are still waiting for the return of Jesus and the garden city where God is going to live with men (new Eden/new Jerusalem). City on a high mountain into which the rivers of people will flow.

**2 And it shall come to pass in the last days, that the mountain of the LORD'S house shall be established in the top of the mountains, and shall be exalted above the hills; and all nations shall flow unto it.** (Isaiah 2)

Answer (score 1):

The latter (blending multiple but originally separate geographic images to describe the ruler's downfall). Since this refers to Eden as the former dwelling place of the king of Tyre, it is best understood metaphorically rather than geographically. Like the King of Babylon in Isaiah 14, this king was once glorious but is to be brought down. The word הַר [har] can mean either mountain or hill, referring to a high place of some sort. But again, the prophet may have been speaking metaphorically. In any case, Tyre was reputed to have housed important temples and fabulous palaces. The bible reports that one of this king's predecessors, namely Hiram, advised and greatly assisted Solomon in building the temple of Jerusalem. [1 Kings 5, 7, 9 and 10] https://www.britannica.com/place/Tyre

Answer (score 0):

The mountain would be the Kingdom of God, heaven of course. Therefore, the garden would be located in the mountain which is heaven. I must say the garden is a movable place that's why it was found on earth in the beginning. However, it was taken back to heaven just before the flood and will be restored in the earth made new. The person whom God was addressing is the angel named Lucifer who became Satan because of his sins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).